# how to get text field value from protractor web driver

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am working on a task where I am automating the front end pages.  There I need to get the text field value whether it is null or not. I am trying to get the suggestion from previous questions but it is not working.

```
browser.driver.findElement(this.filename).sendkeys(this.filenamevalue);

console.log(browser.driver.findElement(this.filename).getAttribute('value'));
```

I am not getting the output which I passed as input through filename value. I am getting the output as some JSON object with all parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve a promise:

```
browser.driver.findElement(this.filename).getAttribute('value').then((elementValue) =) {
    console.log(elementValue)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use async/await instead of resolving the promise.

```
(async()=>{

let elm_text = await browser.driver.findElement(this.filename).getAttribute('value');
console.log(elm_text);

})()
```

If you are writing this snippet inside a function then make the function `async`